# PHP Reference & Class inheritance: error if in one file, two files ok?

Tags: php, reference

I have a problem that I am completely confused with.

The following code throws an error if in one file and also does not deliver the desired function (all data being in all variables), but if I split it up into two files (see remark at line 27) and include the rest of the code being in a separate file then the code works. Can anybody explain why? (or is that a PHP bug?)

Thanks in advance.

```
    $SOME_DATA["A"] = "das ist A";
    $SOME_DATA["B"] = "das ist B";

    abstract class BASIC
    {
        public static $DATA    = array();

        public static function init__()
        {
            static::$DATA =& $GLOBALS['SOME_DATA'];

            static::$DATA['test'] = 0;
            static::$DATA['cnt'] = 0;
        }

        public static function plus( $A_up=1 )
        {
            static::$DATA['cnt']+=$A_up;
        }
    }


    BASIC::init__();

    //-------------- SPLITTING HERE SOLVES THE PROBLEM OF LINE 42 when calling C1::plus(); WHY???
    // include "fileename_of_rest_of_code.php";

    abstract class C1 extends BASIC {}
    abstract class C2 extends BASIC {}


    echo "START------------------------------\n";
    echo "BASIC::\$DATA==="; print_r( BASIC::$DATA );
    echo "C1::\$DATA===";print_r( C1::$DATA );
    echo "C2::\$DATA===";print_r( C2::$DATA );


    echo "USE------------------------------\n";
    C1::$DATA['xyz'] = "oooooooooooo";
    echo "... first use of C1::plus() causes trouble as \$DATA seems to NOT being inherited into C1 as expected";
    C1::plus(7);
    C2::plus(5);
    BASIC::plus(24);


    echo "\n\nEND---------------------------------\n";
    echo "BASIC::\$DATA==="; print_r( BASIC::$DATA );
    echo "C1::\$DATA===";print_r( C1::$DATA );
    echo "C2::\$DATA===";print_r( C2::$DATA );
    echo "GLOBALS['SOME_DATA']===";print_r( $GLOBALS['SOME_DATA'] );
```

[---EDIT---]
RESULT is that the variables GLOBALS['SOME_DATA'], BASIC::$DATA and C1:$DATA do  NOT the same content, but should have!

OUTPUT:

```
START------------------------------
BASIC::$DATA===Array
(
    [A] => das ist A
    [B] => das ist B
    [test] => 0
    [cnt] => 0
)
C1::$DATA===Array
(
)
C2::$DATA===Array
(
)
USE------------------------------
... first use of C1::plus() causes trouble as $DATA seems to NOT being inherited into C1 as expected
Notice:  Undefined index: cnt in C:\IPS\00_LOC\__SLOL_OO\Referenz_problem_small_4.php on line 20


END---------------------------------
BASIC::$DATA===Array
(
    [A] => das ist A
    [B] => das ist B
    [test] => 0
    [cnt] => 24
)
C1::$DATA===Array
(
    [xyz] => oooooooooooo
    [cnt] => 12
)
C2::$DATA===Array
(
    [xyz] => oooooooooooo
    [cnt] => 12
)
GLOBALS['SOME_DATA']===Array
(
    [A] => das ist A
    [B] => das ist B
    [test] => 0
    [cnt] => 24
)
```

Comment: and this error is...?

Comment: actually, it throws only one notice `Notice: Undefined index: cnt` for me

Comment: not 100% sure why yet, but if you remove the reference assignment (`static::$DATA =` vs `static::$DATA =&`) it fixes the issue

Comment: sorry, maybe misleading:

the error is that the three variables $GLOBALS['SOME_DATA'], BASIC::$DATA and C1::$DATA and C2::$DATA do NOT contain the same values even though the Reference and the inheritance should guarantee that.

Comment: @watcher: It solves only the problem of the error, but it will then also "destroy" the reason: I want to have every change to <class>::$DATA being reflected  in global Space and vice versa. That, from my knowledge is only possible by using a reference.